# Timespan between (2) other Timespan when adding / subtracting minutes C#

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, timespan

Everything works with the exception if I pass in "15 minutes". I receive no errors, it's just that my where clause isn't working 100%. This is b/c I pass in time in 15 minute intervals.

Example:

- Object 1 has a time of 00:20 (12:20 am) (24hr format)
- Object 2 has a time of 02:15 (02:15 am) (24hr format)

The *parsedTime* param is a javascript 24hr format time - in this example is comes in as "00:15".

The problem is when I subtract the -30 minutes from the *parsedTime*, it puts it at 23:45, and therefore never gets the "00:20".

LINQ query

```
DateTime parsedTime = DateTime.ParseExact(time, "HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

var activities = objects
          .Where(x => (x.GetValue<DateTime>("startTime").TimeOfDay 
                      >= parsedTime.AddMinutes(-30).TimeOfDay
                 && x.GetValue<DateTime>("startTime").TimeOfDay 
                     <= parsedTime.AddMinutes(30).TimeOfDay))
          .ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, where is the Object 1 and Object 2 in your example? What do you expect to happen when you subtract 30 minutes from 12:15 am? (00:15)?

Comment: Object 1 and 2 are in the CMS, but both objects have a DateTime property that I only really care about the time, not the date. The dates here do not relate at all. When I subtract 30 minutes from 12:15am the `.TimeofDay` turns it into "23:50"

Comment: Can you also check the day/month value?  Technically what the code is doing is 100% correct.  Without the context of what day you're on, the code loses the fact that 23:45 is less than 00:20, in this scenario.  Solely looking at those times, without considering the day, 23:45 is not less than 00:00 and will never satisfy your condition.

Comment: DateTimes, despite the inclusion of a `TimeOfDay` property, always reference a date, when you subtract 30 minutes you will get 11:45 (23:45) from the previous day, it doesn't wrap around.

Comment: @Kalmino - the comment above states the the Dates to not matter at all. Sorry - added right before your comment

Comment: ahh, I see.  Then you might have to do some extra logic on your math to ensure that if a value goes "under" 00:00 it gets set to a base, minimum value; probably 00:00.

Comment: @Kalmino took your suggestion and just added logic to reduce number of subtracted minutes if it went under 00:00 - appreciate it. Thanks everyone else - didn't know that `TimeOfDay` didn't wrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you also need to handle time ranges that could span across midnight, as in the 30 minutes that exists between `"23:45"` and `"00:15"`.  Here's how you can do that:

```
public static TimeSpan GetTimeDifference(string startTimeOfDay, string endTimeOfDay)
{
    DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startTimeOfDay, "HH:mm",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

    DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(endTimeOfDay, "HH:mm",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

    if (endDateTime >= startDateTime)
    {
        // values do not cross over midnight
        return endDateTime - startDateTime;
    }
    else
    {
        // values cross over midnight
        return endDateTime - startDateTime + TimeSpan.FromHours(24);
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer something smaller:

```
public static int GetMinutesDifference(string startTimeOfDay, string endTimeOfDay)
{
    DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startTimeOfDay, "HH:mm",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

    DateTime endDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(endTimeOfDay, "HH:mm",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.NoCurrentDateDefault);

    return (((int)(endDateTime - startDateTime).TotalMinutes + 1440) % 1440);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just want to see if they're within 30 minutes of each other, right?  Try using actual timespans

```
DateTime startTime;
DateTime parsedTime;
TimeSpan difference = startTime - parsedTime;
return difference.TotalMinutes < 30 && difference.TotalMinutes > -30;
```